# JFXTextField gives error while JFXButton works fine

Tags: javafx, controls

Cant find an answer to my problem so far. Maybe you can help.
I am trying to add a JFXTextfield to my javafx application but when I run the program I get errors like:
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getLayoutBounds()" because "this.textNode" is null"

JFXButtons and other controls work fine though.
I have jfoenix 9 jar and javafx 17

How can I get the JFXTextfield to work?

Comment: As far as I can tell, JFoenix has not been updated in a couple of years now. This is an opinion, but the way it was written (lots of access to non-public API classes) it always seemed to me it was going to be difficult or impossible to maintain. Consider using something like [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) instead.